# Connection Pool Java

Tags: java, connection, pool

Here is a ConnectionPool that i implemented. Is it a good design to have all variables and methods as static. Please explain why or why not

```
public class MyCp1 {

    private static final int MAX_SIZE=100;
    private static final BlockingQueue<Connection> bq;

    static{
         System.out.println("Inside begin static block" );
        bq= new ArrayBlockingQueue<Connection>(MAX_SIZE);
        for(int i=0;i<MAX_SIZE;i++)
        {
            try {
                try {
                    bq.put(makeConnection());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("total size:" + bq.size());
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.out.println("size before getting connection "+ bq.size()+ "  Thread name  "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Connection con=bq.take();
        System.out.println("size after getting connection  "+ bq.size()+"  Thread name  "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return (con);
    }

    public static boolean releaseConnection(Connection con) throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.out.println("size before releasing connection  "+ bq.size()+" Thread name  "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
        boolean bool =bq.add(con);
        System.out.println("size after releasing connection  "+ bq.size()+"  Thread name  "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return (bool);
    }

    public static Connection makeConnection() throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = null;
        Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
        connectionProps.put("user", "root");
        connectionProps.put("password", "java33");
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:" + "mysql" + "://"
                + "localhost" + ":" + "3306" + "/test", connectionProps);

        System.out.println("Connected to database");
        return conn;
    }


}
```

I know there are issues with exceptional handling and others, but i would appreciate if you can please stick to the above mentioned question

EDIT::

It looks like using static is not favored. So I refactored as much as i could to get rid of static. While this works, not sure if this is good design

```
 public class ConnectionPool {

    private static final int MAX_SIZE = 100;
    private    BlockingQueue<Connection> bq;
    private static ConnectionPool cp= new ConnectionPool();


    private ConnectionPool(){
        System.out.println("inside constructor");
         bq = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Connection>(MAX_SIZE);
        Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
        connectionProps.put("user", "root");
        connectionProps.put("password", "java33");
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++) {
            try {
                bq.put(makeConnection(connectionProps));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        System.out.println("total size:" + bq.size());
    }
    public static ConnectionPool getInstance()
    {
        return cp;

    }

    public  Connection getConnection() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("size before getting connection" + bq.size());
        Connection con = bq.take();
        System.out.println("size after getting connection" + bq.size());
        return (con);
    }

    public  void releaseConnection(Connection con)
            throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("size before releasing connection" + bq.size());
         bq.put(con);
        System.out.println("size after releasing connection" + bq.size());
        //return (bool);
    }

    private  Connection makeConnection(Properties connectionProps) throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = null;
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:" + "mysql" + "://"
                + "localhost" + ":" + "3306" + "/test", connectionProps);

        System.out.println("Connected to database");
        return conn;
    }

}
```

Comment: No need to write your implementation of a connection pool. Use [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) or [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/) . Why re-invent the wheel? :)

Comment: [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com). Please don't try to reinvent such an extremely important software aspect such as a connection pool as long as you're new to Java and already don't know when to use `static`. It'll kill you sooner or later.

Comment: Is it an exercise? I recommend you use `commons-dbcp` or `c3p0` open source pools.

Comment: While using a connection pool library is better than creating it yourself, there is a lot that can be learned by properly writing your own (or reading the source code of one of the aforementioned libraries).

Comment: @CoolBeans - Don't use DBCP! It's horrible. For example, it blocks threads that are attempting to *return* connections during the time it's trying to create a new connection.

Comment: Others have already pointed out that there are better options for connection pools, but if you persist in using this implementation of yours, I'd like to think about how you intend to handle JTA transaction support, especially in the area of resource enlistment and transaction context recognition.

Comment: @erickson - good to know. I usually just utilize the container connection pool which may or may not use commons-dbcp underneath.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely not. What you have is more of an object recycler, which is fine if that's what you need.

(As a recycler, however, you still don't want static fields, but you'd just create one instance of the recycler.)

For a connection pool (and if this for something like JDBC Connections) it needs to be thread-safe, and ideally you shouldn't need to return the connection.

Connection pools that are thread-safe will use [ThreadLocal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) to return a connection that will only ever be used on that thread. If one is not available, it will then create a new connection by implementing [ThreadLocal.initialValue()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html#initialValue%28%29).

Furthermore, your threads should be created using an [ExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)) so you reuse threads as well.

Comment: There are many ways to make a pool thread-safe. Dedicating a connection to a thread is just one of many, and whether this is the best or even a good approach depends on the circumstances.

Comment: Not much *pooling* in your approach if you use `Executors.newCachedThreadPool` where unused threads die after a 60 second timeout.